# API always returns 200 with no data in the response

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to make a request to api.postcodes.io/postcodes/:postcode/validate, to check if the postcode I have entered is a valid one. If I do this through the website I get a 200 response and a boolean result set to true when I enter a valid postcode and status: 200, result: false when I enter a random number. However, when trying to do this through my code I get no result. What could be the problem? I tried to parse the result using .json() but this just gave me an error.

This is my request:

```
const requestURL = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' + addedPostcode + '/validate';

try {
        console.log("enters try");
        const response = yield fetch(requestURL, {
            method: 'GET',
        });
        if(response.status === 200){
            console.log("enters 200");
            yield put({type: 'SHOW_ALERT', payload: {alertType: 'success', alertMessage: 'POST CODE VALID'}});
            const updatedUser = yield response;
            console.log(updatedUser);
        } else{
            console.log("enters 400");
            const description = 'POST CODE INVALID';
            yield put({type: 'SHOW_MODAL', payload: {type:'error', description}});
            return;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

SOLUTION: Response needed to be parsed using .json(). Reason it was failing before is because my request url was missing the 'https://' part.

Comment: Where is in your code the value you are trying to validate? Is it already a part of `requestURL`?

Comment: I added it in the new edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think they alway return a status of 200. But if you enter a valid UK zip code they return

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "result": true
}
```

otherwise they return "result": false.

I've tested it with the following request url: `api.postcodes.io/postcodes/SO152GB/validate`

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this, will resturcuture my question as I do not receive any result

Comment: He's looking statusCode of fetch request, not in body.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

`if(response.status === 200){`

to this

`if(response.result && response.result === true){`

Comment: I think response.result not available in this way. It's need to JSONize.

Answer (score 0):

There are two status in this request and I think you're confused a bit.

First status is coming from fetch request.
Second is coming from response body.

You can check these statuses that way:

```js
const requestURL = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/SO152GB/validate';

const response = await fetch(requestURL, {
            method: 'GET',
        });
        
if(response.status === 200) {
  // you can access to body with this way.
  const body = await response.json();
  
  if(body.status === 200) {
    // your business
  }
}
```